# How to find the faulty URL? of No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: web, error-handling, http-error

I often have this problem with web development. Where some kind of connection is not working but the system involves many connections. So it can be difficult to isolate which one is going wrong. Sometimes the URL is included, but why not always? Is there a way to find it out?
I have multiple Event Viewer errors with stack trace and that helps. But I'd much rather have the actual URL that was reqested.